# Winservice - Timer: Same task being executed parallel

Tags: c#, windows-services, system.timers.timer

I've made a Window-Service which performs an action after each. We've declared the timer as follows:

```
using System.Timers;

....

Int32 myInterval = 60000 * (Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["lpInterval"].ToString()));
_myTimer = new Timer();
_myTimer.Interval = myInterval;
_myTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(TimerElapsed);

    //Timer-Tick
private void TimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{ PerformAction(); }
```

What have noticed: 
If `PerformAction()` takes longer then my `interval` (due to WCF-Services or Serverissues) then an new `'instance'` of `PerformAction` is launched and executed. So the `PerformAction` is running twice (and `parallel`) to each other.

What is the cause of this? Why isn't the previous `PerformAction` being cancelled? Is the method `PerformAction` being executed `Async`?

I've found a workaround but I just don't understand the behavior...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you run your action stop the timer then after perform action start the timer again

```
private void TimerElapsed(object source, ElapsedEventArgs e)
{ 
    _myTimer.Stop();
    PerformAction();
    _myTimer.Start();
}
```

System.Timers

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.elapsed%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

the Elapsed event is raised on a ThreadPool thread. If the processing of the Elapsed event lasts longer than Interval, the event might be raised again on another ThreadPool thread. In this situation, the event handler should be reentrant.

Elapsed events can occur after the Dispose or Stop method has been called or after the Enabled property has been set to false, because the signal to raise the Elapsed event is always queued for execution on a thread pool thread. One way to resolve this race condition is to set a flag that tells the event handler for the Elapsed event to ignore subsequent events.

Comment: I know that now. But i wasn't looking for the solution. I was looking for the reason why the previous action isn't cancelled.

Comment: It spawns on a ThreadPool thread so it doesn't cancel it just spawns another thread to run on.

Comment: But isn't that only for objects of type System.Threading.Timers...?

Answer (score 1):

It's simply a design decision of the timer.  It has a number of possible resolutions, ranging from firing the events in parallel, queuing the handlers until immediately after the previous handler finishes, to skipping that particular event entirely.  The designers choose that option.  They could just as easily have chosen another, as designers of certain other timers have done.

As for why it's not cancelled, cancelling code non-cooperatively is **very** dangerous and extremely error prone, and implements of tick handlers are generally not going to feel the need to implement cooperative cancellation (they could do so using the existing implementation if they really wanted to anyway) so this is not really a practical option.